# Hey, I need help in python

Tags: python, random, pygame

I wanna to make a program that generate a line with random shape of blocks. I did well so far. But I dont want to def every single block. Is there a way to do a def function in for to every time when for happened def something else? If not how can i def 10 objects with not just copy and pasting 10 times and changing names. I wanna to my code be more compact, Thanks for reading! I also added a project if I didnt explain well what I am trying to do

```
import random
import pygame

pygame.init()
black = 0, 0, 0
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

BlockImg = pygame.image.load('cobblestone.png')
blockX = random.randint(0, 800)
blockY = random.randint(0, 600)

position = random.randint(1, 6)
if position == 1:
    block2X = blockX - 16
    block2Y = blockY
if position == 2:
    block2X = blockX + 16
    block2Y = blockY
if position == 3:
    block2X = blockX
    block2Y = blockY - 16
if position == 4:
    block2X = blockX + 16
    block2Y = blockY - 16
if position == 5:
    block2X = blockX + 16
    block2Y = blockY + 16
if position == 6:
    block2X = blockX - 16
    block2Y = blockY + 16

positionoftwo = random.randint(1, 6)
if positionoftwo == 1:
    block3X = blockX - 16
    block3Y = blockY
if positionoftwo == 2:
    block3X = block2X + 16
    block3Y = block2Y
if positionoftwo == 3:
    block3X = block2X
    block3Y = block2Y - 16
if positionoftwo == 4:
    block3X = block2X + 16
    block3Y = block2Y - 16
if positionoftwo == 5:
    block3X = block2X + 16
    block3Y = block2Y + 16
if positionoftwo == 6:
    block3X = block2X - 16
    block3Y = block2Y + 16


# can I automate that?

def one(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


def two(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


def three(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


def four(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


def five(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


def six(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


def seven(x, y):
    screen.blit(BlockImg, (x, y))


running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(black)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    one(blockX, blockY)
    two(block2X, block2Y)
    three(block3X, block3Y)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You seem to have repeated the same function. What is wrong with just keeping `def one(x,y):` and using that over and over?

Comment: put code in `def`  and use `return values` so later ca use `block2X, block2Y = function()`. AND learn how to use list for objects `blocks = [(X1, Y1), (X2, Y2), ...]` and then you can use `for`-loop and `one()` to make it simple `for x,y in blocks: one(x,y) `

Comment: Thanks... I am dumb. yee really thx

Comment: you have the same code in `one()`, `two()` `three()` so instead of `one(blockX, blockY)`, `two(block2X, block2Y)` , `three(block3X, block3Y)`  you can the same function with different variables `one(blockX, blockY)` `one(block2X, block2Y)` `one(block3X, block3Y)`

Answer (score 1):

You have the same code in `one()`, `two()`, `three()`, etc. so you can keep only one of them and run it many times but with different arguments

```
one(blockX, blockY)
one(block2X, block2Y)
one(block3X, block3Y)
```

---

You should put code in function and use `return` to run many times and assign returned values to different varaibles

```
def generate_block():

    X = random.randint(0, 800)
    Y = random.randint(0, 600)
    
    position = random.randint(1, 6)

    if position == 1:
        X = X - 16
    if position == 2:
        X = X + 16
    if position == 3:
        Y = Y - 16
    if position == 4:
        X = X + 16
        Y = Y - 16
    if position == 5:
        X = X + 16
        Y = Y + 16
    if position == 6:
        X = X - 16
        Y = Y + 16

    resturn X, Y
```

and

```
blockX, blockY = generate_block()
block2X, block2Y = generate_block()
block3X, block3Y = generate_block()
# ... 10 times ...
```

but it would be better to keep it on list

```
all_blocks = []

x, y = generate_block()
all_blocks.append( (x,y) )

x, y = generate_block()
all_blocks.append( (x,y) )

x, y = generate_block()
all_blocks.append( (x,y) )

# ... 10 times ...
```

or simpler

```
all_blocks = []

for _ in range(10):  # <- it will repeate it 10 times
    x, y = generate_block()
    all_blocks.append( (x,y) )
```

and later you can use `for`-loop to use all blocks

```
for x, y in all_blocks:  # <- `all_blocks` has 10 items 
    one(x, y)            #     so it will repeate it 10 times
```

---

**EDIT:**

Working code

```
import random
import pygame

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

FPS = 16  # Frames Per Seconds

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN_SIZE = (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions

def generate_block():
    x = random.randint(0, 800)
    y = random.randint(0, 600)

    position = random.randint(1, 6)
    
    if position == 1:
        x = x - 16
    if position == 2:
        x = x + 16
    if position == 3:
        y = y - 16
    if position == 4:
        x = x + 16
        y = y - 16
    if position == 5:
        x = x + 16
        y = y + 16
    if position == 6:
        x = x - 16
        y = y + 16

    return x, y

def draw(screen, image, rect):
    screen.blit(image, rect)

# --- main ---

# - init -
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - objects -

#block_image = pygame.image.load('cobblestone.png')  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
block_image = pygame.image.load('[![enter image description here][1]][1]square-1.png')  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

all_blocks = []
for _ in range(10):
    x, y = generate_block()
    #block_rect = block_image.get_rect()
    #block_rect.x = x
    #block_rect.y = y
    block_rect = block_image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
    all_blocks.append( block_rect )
    
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 150)    
text_image = font.render("PAUSE", True, GREEN)
text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

# - loop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
paused = False

while running:
    # - only events -
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: # exit on pressing ESC
                running = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: # pause/unpause on pressing SPACE
                paused = not paused

    # - only updates -
    
    if not paused:
        for block_rect in all_blocks:
            block_rect.x += random.randint(-15, 15)
            block_rect.y += random.randint(-15, 15) 
    
    # - only draws -
    
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    for block_rect in all_blocks:
        draw(screen, block_image, block_rect)

    if paused:
        draw(screen, text_image, text_rect)
        
    pygame.display.update()
    
    clock.tick(FPS) # slow down to 15 FPS (Frames Per Second)
    
# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

square-1.png , square-2.png , square-3.png ,

[image]
[image]
[image]

Results:

[image]

Doc: [Font](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html), [Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), [Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)